# Visual C++ Assembly link library troubles

Tags: assembly, visual-studio-2008, include, masm, irvine32

I'm having a problem having my projects built in VC++ Express 2008... 
I'm using a library, irvine32.inc/lib. INCLUDE Irvine32.inc works for me at school (On already configured VS environments) by default, but at home (Windows 7 x64) I'm having a boatload of issues.
My original post here was that a file that irvine32.inc referenced, in the same folder, 'could not be opened.' Added irvine folder to the include path for specific project, progress.
Then I was getting an error with mt.exe, but a suggestion on the MSDN suggested turn off antivirus, and now project does build but when I run a program that does NOT reference anything in irvine32, it tells me repeatedly that my project has triggered a breakpoint, and allows me to continue or break. Continue just pops the same window, break loads another popup telling me that "No symbols are loaded for any call stack frame. Source code cannot be displayed." This popup lets me view the disassembly.

I tested it with and without working statements, it just throws the same breakpoint on the first line of code. Now, if I run the program when it DOES require something from the include file, in this case, DumpRegs:

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data

.code
main PROC
mov ebx,1000h
mov eax,1000h
add eax,ebx
call DumpRegs

main ENDP
END main
```

This gives me

1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _DumpRegs@0 referenced in function _main@0
1>C:\Users\Cameron\csis165\Lab8_CCarroll\Debug\Lab8_CCarroll.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

This does NOT happen when I build a project from the book author's examples, which has the same include statement.

I'm baffled. :(

Answer (score -1):

Wrong project template I guess. _DumpRegs@0  is clearly C++, not C or assembly language. My assembly language instructor's first class was about setting up the make file. Are you using a makefile project?

Comment: The first sentence is utterly wrong. The second sentence is not constructive. The third sentence is just a request for clarification.